# Shared folder with same name

Tags: finder, network, sharing

On our network we have 2 network drives both with a folder named 'Shared', `//driveA/Shared` and `//driveB/Shared`. When someone connects to `//driveA/Shared`, then connects to `//driveB/Shared`, the `//driveB/Shared` folder overwrites the `//driveA/Shared` folder, because they are both named Shared. Even though it looks like both are connected, it can not find files from `//driveA/Shared`. So people can not have both folders open at the same time. I tried manually mounting them with:

```
mount -t smbfs //drive1/Shared ~/drive1
mount -t smbfs //drive2/Shared ~/drive2
```

However, the problem still persist. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you change the domain names to simplify the problem, 
say if they are in different room, use... R22shared and R23shared, or Serv1 shared / Serv2shared, this may get rid of you problem.